# php curl fails because of url

Tags: php, curl

I wrote a script that is sending some data to an external server. Everything is working fine so far. The problem is when I'm building the url by a variable, which is necessary, the post request won't succeed. When I'm echoing out both variables they're exactly the same. The `$action` variable is coming through an array and has the value of `/index.php?param=value`.

```
$regexp = '/<form(.*?)action="(.*?)"(.*?)>(.*?)<\/form>/';
preg_match_all($regexp, $body, $form);

$action = $form[2][0];

$url = 'https://www.homepage.com/index.php?param=value';    // success
$url = 'https://www.homepage.com'.$action;                  // no success

$post_data = array(
        'param1' => 'value1',
        'param2' => 'value2'
);

$data = array(
        'url'       => $url,
        'post_data' => $post_data
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.3) Gecko/20070309 Firefox/2.0.0.3 AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "" );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, getcwd () . '/cookie.txt' );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, getcwd () . '/cookie.txt' );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_exec($ch);
```

There is no `curl_error($ch)` and for `curl_getinfo($ch)` I get the following in both cases:

```
Array
(
    [url] => https://www.homepage.com/index.php?param=value
    [content_type] => text/html; charset=utf-8
    [http_code] => 200
    [header_size] => 437
    [request_size] => 865
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 0.12154
    [namelookup_time] => 2.1E-5
    [connect_time] => 0.003557
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.014587
    [size_upload] => 468
    [size_download] => 1248
    [speed_download] => 10268
    [speed_upload] => 3850
    [download_content_length] => -1
    [upload_content_length] => 468
    [starttransfer_time] => 0.057372
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [redirect_url] => 
    [primary_ip] => 00.00.00.00    // changed by myself
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [primary_port] => 443
    [local_ip] => 000.000.000.000    // changed by myself
    [local_port] => 62352
)
```

**EDIT**

When I am doing

```
$url_1  = 'https://www.homepage.com/index.php?param=value';    // success
$url_2  = 'https://www.homepage.com'.$action;                  // no success

if ($url_1 == $url_2) {
    echo 'MATCH';
} else {
    echo $url_1.'_';
    echo $url_2.'_';
}
```

I get the else statement. So they are not the same. But they are looking identically. `_` in else statement is for looking after white spaces.

Comment: what is the value of $action?

Comment: @LuckyChingi the value of `$action` is `/index.php?param=value`

Comment: can you also send me the value of $form? I am checking it on my pc

Comment: @LuckyChingi I can't give you this because it's kind of a sensitive data. But as I said the value of `$form[2][0]` is correct. After I run that script in the non succeeded way I echoed out `$url`. Then I used this string and replaced it for `$url` in the script and it worked. So maybe `$action` hasn't the right format or isn't a string or something like that.

Comment: what you're describing is nigh-impossible. bin2hex() the 2 variants, and tell me, are the bin2hex()-encoded strings exactly the same? there's probably a difficult-to-spot encoding or whitespace or newline difference

Comment: @hanshenrik I did an edit. So what could I do?

Comment: @p.allows First check the bin2hex() values as suggested. If they are different you will have to identify the offending character and try to remove it. Maybe a simple `trim($action)` will do it.

Comment: @dan08 Thank you so much! That did it.